# IE8 / 9 Outerglow issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm experiencing a weird issue in IE 8/9 involving outer glow. I've a modal box (created by jQuery UI) with outer glow applied to it. The height of the box is increased or decreased based on the options you select in the box (simple show hide JS) the problem is when the height on the box decreases it leaves behind marks/traces of outer glow horizontally and they disappear as soon as you click anywhere on the screen.

It seems like when the height is changed IE for some weird reason doesn't refresh the view port properly.

Comment: Could you please give us a code example and clarify your question?

Comment: I couldn't attach an image to the post .. I've uploaded it here please see and let me know if it helps explaining my issue http://postimage.org/image/aw9rqni6f/

Answer (score 1):

You can force a UI redraw:

```
$('body').addClass('js').removeClass('js');
```

see also:

[Forcing a UI redraw from JavaScript - Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript)

Comment: Can you please see the image at this link: (being a new member I couldn't attacch the image) http://postimage.org/image/aw9rqni6f/ and see if it explains the poblem?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code - I can only guess, but some known solutions around this issue are...

Make sure you have a valid DOCTYPE -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

also try adding this to the to the element that box-shadow is not working properly on.

```
border-collapse: separate;
```